# Como obter o menor valor em uma lista?

Tags: python, funções

Estou travado nesse programa, não consigo criar uma função em Python.

O exercício é o seguinte:

> Escreva uma função chamada buscarMenor() que recebe uma lista de inteiros e retorna o menor dos elementos. Escreva, também, o programa principal que passa a lista para a função e exibe o retorno. A busca pelo menor elemento deve ser efetuada utilizando estrutura de repetição, sendo vedado o uso da função min(). Exemplo:

Entrada: 7.0 5.5 6.0 9.0
Saída: 5.5

O que fiz até agora:

```
listaInteiros = []
i = 0

while i < 4:
    inteiros = int(input())
    listaInteiros.append(inteiros)
    i += 1
print(listaInteiros)

def buscarMenor():
```

Estou travado na função, me deem uma força por favor!

Comment: De acordo com a [**PEP8**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names), nome de funções devem utilizar [*snake case*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) (embora existam outras várias formas de chamar isto). Já que está aprendendo, tente desde já seguir as convenções. Sua função `buscarMenor` preferencialmente deve se chamar `buscar_menor`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sugestão:

```
def buscarMenor(lst):
    i = float("inf")
    for nr in lst:
        if nr < i:
            i = nr
    return i

listaInteiros = [7, 5, 6, 9]
menor = buscarMenor(listaInteiros)
print(menor) # 5

listaDecimais = [7.0, 5.5, 6.0, 9.0]
menor = buscarMenor(listaDecimais)
print(menor) # 5.5
```

Por passos seria:

- defenir a função
- dar o maior valor possivel na declaração/atribuição de `i`
- iterar os numeros da lists
- se o numero iterado fôr menor que o `i`, subsituir o i por esse

Depois para correr é só chamar a função com uma lista de numeros e guardar o seu retorno numa variável.

Comment: O que é o argumento lst?

Comment: @Pigot É uma lista/array, encurtei o nome..., podes dar outro nome se quiseres, mas é o que passas à função em `buscarMenor(listaInteiros)`

Comment: Tem como esclarecer melhor o programa todo pra mim? Tô em dúvida

Comment: @Pigot viste o final da resposta onde escrevo "por passos"? qual a parte que compreendes e qual a parte que não compreendes? (para eu poder ser mais claro)

Comment: Como faço pra chamar dois argumentos no programa principal?

Comment: @Pigot podes passar mais argumentos à função separados por virgulas. E dentro da função receber um a um. Faz sentido?

Comment: Valeu cara, me ajudou muito!!

Answer (score 0):

```
def buscarMenor(lista):
    menor = lista[0]
for i in lista:
    if i < menor:
        menor = i
return menor
print(buscarMenor([7.0,5.5,6.0,9.0]))
```

Comment: Mal pergunte, porque está repostando tantas vezes a resposta? Não há necessidade disso, é para essa finalidade que existe o botao EDITAR logo abaixo, para que você corrija o que precisar ser corrigido ao inves de ter que criar um novo post.

Answer (score -3):

Voce pode usar a funcao min ou max para conseguir o menor valor ou o maior valor de uma lista:

'menor = min(listaInteiros)'